# Interconnection of a Midi music keyboard from its DIN5 socket to USB input on my Laptop

Tags: laptop, usb, keyboard, midi

I have an old Evolution Mk149 music keyboard which has a DIN 5 connector at the keyboard and a 15 pin 'D'connector at the other end.   On my new laptop computer there are no compatable connections.  As the keyboard needs to draw power through its interconnecting cable, would a connecting lead of Din 5 to USB provide a working solution?  If so, Where can I get one?  I have searched the web and not found one.
Question 571252 gets close to my problem but involves an old text keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll need something like this [MIDI to USB converter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Adapter-USB-to-Midi-In-Out/dp/B000XRI3CC).

As for providing the power, the Evolution MK-149 is capable of being powered by an AC adapter according to the [manual](http://www.m-audio.com/images/global/manuals/mk149eng.pdf).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your [pointed question](https://superuser.com/questions/571252/din5-plug-adapter-to-usb) actually answers a lot.

A DIN5 connector (aka a MIDI connector) is *physically* the same as a PS/2 connector. The main reason why I don't see DIN5 to USB converters is because DIN5 isn't as used in modern PC's as PS/2 ports, that have also phased out to favor USB.

Now, it **could** work, since USB hosts can supply power (and so can PS/2 ports). According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub#Power):

> USB current (related to power) is allocated in units of 100 mA up to a maximum total of 500 mA per port. Therefore a compliant bus powered hub can have no more than four downstream ports and cannot offer more than four 100 mA units of current in total to downstream devices (since the hub needs one unit for itself). If a device requires more units of current than the port it is plugged into can supply, the operating system usually reports this to the user.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector) yet again, Pin 4 of the PS/2 connector outputs `+5 V DC at 275 mA`

According to the [maker's manual](http://www.m-audio.com/images/global/manuals/mk149eng.pdf) for your keyboard:

> You can also use an AC adapter with the following specification: 9-12V DC output, 250-300mA, centre positive

Both the PS/2 and USB signal voltage is `5V`. However, just converting a DIN5 to PS/2 to USB isn't going to work. Mainly because of the fact the HSB host has no way of figuring out the amount of power the keyboard needs.

So, for this to work, you need an active converter, that by some way tells the USB host how many mA's the device needs. This for powering the keyboard. As for transferring data, you hit a snag. Not existing supporting drivers and the fact you're converting a lot of things. But, assuming you could write an application that read the output of the USB and converted it to the DIN5 one (or maybe fool the system into thinking the USB is a DIN5) there you would not have problems.

But like I said, and as far as I've searched, it's a yet-to-be solved problem. Mainly because of the age of the technology. Although the [link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Adapter-USB-to-Midi-In-Out/dp/B000XRI3CC) pointed out by @oscillik seems promising.